# SO-style Markups for References in the Bottom of the Page in Bibtex-ed Document?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, formatting

I often have a long bibliography and then later I find that I should have a notice like this buying-list in a project (not that important so not wanting them to the bibtex). I find it overkill to explain a trivia like a buying-list-notice next to more important things in Bibtex, I need just SO-style references. How can I add the references nicely to the bottom of the page instead of the back with author/howpublished/title-bibtex-clutter? I am not against Bibtex but I am looking for more casual referencing besides Bibtex.

```
\begin{itemize}
\item 4pcs [1] (24USD)  % Here [1] and [2] are references to 
\item 2pcs [2] (25USD)  % the below thing with the urls.
\item ...
\end{itemize}

<<echo=FALSE>>   % I am not sure about the parameters here but they 
                 % but they could be things like fonts etc.
                 %
                 % I want here a Sweave-like -tool
                 % for easy mark-up references that will
                 % automatically appear at the bottom of the page.
                 % Then just latexmk to handle compiling?
[1]: http://www.something.com/buyThis/XYZmoment
[2]: http://www.hello.com/notImportantButForTheFuture/GoodToKnowWhereToBuy
%
```

Comment: This is not clear at all, since both answers below provide something in terms of your first edit. After your edit you want a `sweave`-like tool? Moreover, please elaborate on what is meant by "SO-style references".

Comment: @Werner: SO = StackOverflow (actually valid on this site for referencing), I am trying to reuse the references on this site to my latex document without needing to reinvent the wheel by always changing from one markup into another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think footnotes would work, but I'm not sure if I'm missing something:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt]{article} % paper and font chosen to make screenshot smaller
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item 4pcs \footnote{\url{http://www.something.com/buyThis/XYZmoment}} (24USD)
\item 2pcs \footnote{\url{http://www.hello.com/notImportantButForTheFuture/GoodToKnowWhereToBuy}} (25USD)
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I like this because it is succint +1. It would be cool if I could somehow hide those `"\footnote{\url{...}}` with simply `[1] for referencing` and `[1]: www.something.com` for the target so I could use the same SO-style referencing as on this site, possible? Perhaps some macro (I used the term Sweave -style in trying to clarify this, hopefully not distracted, trying to point out the different environment for parsing). Small usability thing to help writing like in SO.

Comment: I wonder if you might be better off using MarkDown or MultiMarkDown for the document, inserting LaTeX as needed for equations as such. I can't look at the syntax at the moment, but that may solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation that uses its own counter `shorturl` to typeset these per-page references as part of the footnotes on the page:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=200pt]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
  % The above paperheight configuration is just for this example
\usepackage{url}% http://ctan.org/pkg/url
\usepackage{perpage}% http://ctan.org/pkg/perpage
\MakePerPage{shorturl}% shorturl counter will reset every page
\newcounter{shorturl}\renewcommand{\theshorturl}{\arabic{shorturl}}%
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\shorturl}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{shorturl}%
  \hbox{\normalfont[\theshorturl]}%
  \insert\footins{%
    \reset@font\footnotesize
    \interlinepenalty\interfootnotelinepenalty
    \splittopskip\footnotesep
    \splitmaxdepth \dp\strutbox \floatingpenalty \@MM
    \hsize\columnwidth \@parboxrestore
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel{%
       \csname p@shorturl\endcsname\theshorturl
    }%
    \color@begingroup
      \par\makebox[1.8em][r]{[\theshorturl]:\ }%
        \rule\z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces#1\@finalstrut\strutbox%
    \color@endgroup}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Some information\footnote{Here is a footnote.}
  \item 4pcs \shorturl{\url{http://www.something.com/buyThis/XYZmoment}} (24USD)
  \item 2pcs \shorturl{\url{http://www.hello.com/notImportantButForTheFuture/GoodToKnowWhereToBuy}} (24USD)
  \item Something else\footnote{This is another footnote.}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Loading [`perpage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/perpage) makes the `\shorturl` references restart every page. Remove this if it is of no concern. It would be possible to modify the layout of the URL in the footnote. At the moment, the `\shorturl` mark within the footnote is right-aligned in a `1.8em` box (similar to that of the regular `\footnote`).

[`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) was just loaded to make the text and footnote be visible/close together.